# Good practice for using almost identical sprites in phaser. Alternatives to using more sprites

Tags: sprite, phaser-framework

So, I have been working in Unity but I've decided it's time to change to something I know better: JavaScript. I've been considering switching to Phaser.js but I have some questions regarding an issue I've been having even in Unity and that I found no solution to at the moment while searching on the internet. I have no code to provide as I haven't yet started actually programming in Phaser, so I'll try to be explicit.

My game idea basically revolves around some lights that change colors. The sprites I have for the lights look identical, but just with different colors, but not entirely (only parts of them are colored differently). The problem is that my game has many different colored lights and it has to change between them. Like, if one light is red and you click on it, it becomes green, for example. Creating and loading so many sprites that look almost the same seems like a bad practice, and I wonder if there is a way to change the color of a sprite or a part of the sprite by code. I know that Phaser doesn't support svg and that svg in games is a bad idea in general because of performance issues but it would have saved me a lot of time to just add the generated svg code of the sprites I use and just change the fill of the parts I want.

So, my question is: what are the best alternatives (if any) to using multiple sprites or how can you change the color of specific parts of them?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, depending upon your light sprites, is to use Phaser's tinting capabilities.

Both sprites and images in Phaser can be tinted, and since Phaser supports sprite grouping, even if you wanted to change only a part of the image you could easily have each displayed object consist of two sprites, one of which is the same for all lights (the part that doesn't change) and another that is also shared, but tinted.

[Phaser 3 example of tinting an image](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/display%5Ctint%5Cmultiple%20images.js):

```
this.add.image(300, 300, 'pixel').setTint(0xff0000);
```

Phaser 3's [`setTint()` documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite.html#setTint__anchor).

[Phaser 2 CE example of tinting a sprite](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/sprite-tint), in case you're looking at using this version:

```
sprite = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'atlas', 'greenJellyfish0000');
sprite.tint = Math.random() * 0xffffff;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for this method.

Answer (score 0):

If the lights don’t have to move, then you can just have a few images and change their src’s. Alternatively, I believe you could have it so that when the sprite is clicked it changes to a different looking animation. That is, after all, the point of a spritesheet, isn’t it?

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid. You see, I have more designs for my lights. Each design comes with 5 colors and it would have been great to be a way so I don't have to create 5 different sprites for each design.

Comment: Oh, wait, so I could create a spritesheet for each design. Yeah, that would be a good idea. I feel stupid for not thinking of this. Thank you

Comment: Also something to take into consideration; if important game elements only differ in colors, this makes the game unplayable for people who are colorblind. So maybe you are better off using different sprites and add dots or stripes, and then use GIMP or PhotoShop scripting to "compile" these sprites.

Comment: Btw you can also automate the process of creating your sprites beforehand, so not at run-time. For an example, see something like this -> https://github.com/BdR76/process_icon_buttons